# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 6342. Current pointers for thread Thread[SDK 28 Main Thread,5,SDK 28] []

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, robolectric

While running unit test I am getting following error which is using room DB.

```
 @Test
    fun validateReceptionRequested_nothingChanged() {
  
        every { receptionRepository.hasConnectivity } returns false
        every { userViewModel.currentUser } returns UserModel(
            fullName= "Doe John",
            userId = "user",
            firstName = "John",
            lastName = "Doe",
            role = Role.OPERATOR
        )

        // When
        vm.validateReceptionRequested(comment)

        // Then
        vm.sendVehicleStatus(vm.comments, VehicleStatus.RECEPTION_OK)
    }
```

getting following error :

```
 Illegal connection pointer 6342. Current pointers for thread Thread[SDK 28 Main Thread,5,SDK 28] []
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 6342. Current pointers for thread Thread[SDK 28 Main Thread,5,SDK 28] []
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.getConnection(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:369)
```